# PerformSegue in StoryBoard

Tags: iphone

I am working for the first time on storyboard using Swift. 
In the first page of the app user will login and when login is done successfully, user will navigate to next page. 
But When button is clicked firstly navigation occurs then after web service gets called, but what I want is to authenticate the Login Web service first then navigate with login data to next page.

I have put the identifier on the login button i.e, "login_success" on the button in storyboard and called self.performSegueWithIdentifier, when login is successfull.

Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add segue in the identifier in storyboard. Set the segue in the storyboard from File Owner. And when we get the response from the server, then using,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
 if self.loginInfo.userEmail.length > 0{
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login_success", sender: self)
 }        
})
```

Here, I am checking whether response string has value or not.

Then call the method of segue to navigate to next page.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
```

{

```
 if segue.identifier == "login_success"
```

{

```
var mainVC: MainViewController!
mainVC = segue.destinationViewController as MainViewController
mainVC.mainLoginInfo = loginInfo
}
}
```

MainViewController is the page to which I want to move after login is done successfully.